# P5.JS Key Pressed Function restricting me

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I'm making a shop kind of place and I'm trying to let the player purchase the first item in the shop's object array by pressing the number 0 but the key pressed isn't letting me access into the if statement. I'm able to tell it is because of the key because when I removed that restriction I was allowed access into the if statement.

```
else if (inShop === true && key === "1") {
  if (player.coins > 50) {
    var buying = true
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < shop.length; i++) {
    console.log(shop[i].name, shop[i].price + " press " + i + " to purchase")
  }
}
  if (buying === true && player.coins > shop[0].price && key=== "0") {
    console.log("yo")
      player.coins = player.coins - shop[0].price
      console.log(player.coins)
      sceneNumber = sceneNumber + 1

}
```

Comment: You might want to double check you're not accidentally running into [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#JavaScript). If you have a variable called `buying` either global or at least in the of `keyPressed()` you might be shadowing it here: `var buying = true`. You probably meant `buying = true` (without the `var` keywoard) ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is all in the `keyPressed` block, I think I know what your problem is.

When you press any key, whatever key is pressed is saved as the `key` variable. Then the computer runs the code that's in the `keyPressed` block. It does not listen for user input in the middle of that block, but waits until the end. Sort of like this (I might have some details wrong):

- run `setup` block
- listen for user input: no input heard
- run `draw` block
- listen for user input: no input heard
- REPEAT the above 2 things over and over
- run `draw` block
- listen for user input: the "1" key was pressed
- `key = '1'; keyCode = 49;`
- run `keyPressed` block
- run `draw` block
- etc.

That pretty much means that you can't do multiple layers of input in the `keyPressed` block. Since `buying === true` only if `key === '1'`, the statement `buying === true && key === "0"` is *always false*.

Often, the `keyPressed` block will look something like this:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (key === "1") {
    ...
  } else if (key === "2") {
    ...
  } ...
}
```

One solution is to turn `buying` into a global variable:

```
let buying = false;
function setup() {
  ...
}

function draw() {
  ...
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key === "1") {
    if (inShop) {
      if (player.coins > 50) {
        buying = true;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < shop.length; i++) {
        console.log(shop[i].name, shop[i].price + " press " + i + " to purchase");
      }
    }
  } else if (key === "0") {
    if (buying && player.coins > shop[0].price) {
      console.log("yo");
      player.coins = player.coins - shop[0].price;
      console.log(player.coins);
      sceneNumber = sceneNumber + 1;
      buying = false; //I don't know if you'd want this to happen.
    }
  }
}
```